# TypeScript type definitions IntelliSense errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

With Visual Studio 2022, I have a lot of IntelliSense errors in the error list window about type definitions of the node_modules folder.
In my tsconfig.json file, I excluded the node_modules folder : `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`.
In my csproj, I added the line `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>`.
But nothing works, I didn't succeed in removing these errors.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart VS? Something similar is happening in other IDEs and in order to deal with such cases we need to restart typescript service.

Comment: I restart it every morning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in Visual Studio 2022 17.3.

Answer (score 3):

After lots of trial and error, I've gotten `"exclude": ["./node_modules/**/*.*"]` to successfully ignore node_modules. It didn't take effect until I restarted Visual Studio.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I also tried "skipLibCheck": true but I have always these errors.

Comment: I don't think this is an ideal solution, it's a workaround. If you could share with us the details of tsconfig and typescript version, then we all can figure out the ideal solution for you. By default, `exclude` excludes the `node_module`. You don't need to explicitly define it.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your tsconfig - can you share your setup? Will want to exclude your dist file as well as your node_modules (and if you want tests/spec files).

`"exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "dist"]`

Webpack has not exported member compilation was the error i saw first - what are you importing with that? [Docs here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) for webpack and typescript.

Wondering if your types are discoverable, could try adding below to tsconfig

```
"typeRoots": [
   "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

Comment: This is my tsconfig.json :
```{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "bin",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I use webpack to compile the typescript files, that's why I added the line `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` in my csproj.